# Const receiving another constant

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Why PHP / laravel informs me a "class not found" error even passing the complete namespace in the assignment of values ​​in the constants?

I'm running a background process using `php artisan`, and there is a specific class that assigns a constant to a constant of another generic class.

```
FILE_1: 

namespace App\Elasticsearch;
class Errors
{
   const UPDATE_DOCUMENT = 'xxx';
}
```

---

```
FILE_2:

namespace App\Services\Exceptions;
class UpdateDocumentException 
{
  const ERROR = \App\Elasticsearch\Errors::UPDATE_DOCUMENT;
}
```

When I execute the command like this, it displays the message : 
**Class 'App\Elasticsearch\Errors' not found**

When I put **use** of class **Errors** below the declaration of **namespace** in **FILE_2**, it works correctly, the difference below follows:

```
FILE_2:

namespace App\Services\Exceptions;
use App\Elasticsearch\Errors;

class UpdateDocumentException extends DocumentException 
{
  const ERROR = Errors::UPDATE_DOCUMENT;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that make the answer self evident

Comment: @RiggsFolly Does it? Both uses should be equivalent.

Comment: As @deceze said, both cases should work.
If you RiggsFolly think this is all obvious, show me the point I'm making so that not only I, but the others with the same problem can solve and understand the real reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by running the command : **composer dump-autoload**